# Adding values to Jira Issue picker custom field using python

Tags: python, api, jira, custom-fields

I'm trying to add some values to a issue picker custom field in Jira, using Python.

**I'm getting** `<Response [405]>` **and no value has been added.**

*The code I'm running*:

```
import requests
import json

key = "TES-78"
Cus1 = "customer_name"

url = "https://**Company_Name**/rest/api/2/issue/"+key

headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Basic **************',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=***; atlassian.xsrf.token=***'
}

payload = json.dumps({

"update": {
   "customfield_12301": [{"add": {"summary": Cus1}}]
}
})

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response)
```

anyone knows how can I add values to the issue picker field?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP 405` is "`Method Not Allowed`": [Mozilla Developer link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)

So, the server just telling you that you should use different HTTP method.

For updating a custom field value in Jira, you should use "`PUT`" method instead of "`POST`".

You can find details from [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/) Atlassian Developer page.